# Using Javascript to queue cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there a way, using javascript, to stop cookie being set instantly and maybe queing them up instead? For example, Google analytics cookies?

I apologise is this question isn't much more detailed but I have no clue where to look, I have tried searching for various terms.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Queuing them up until when? Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to conform to the EU cookie law and I want to just drop in one script tag for all our clients. So I will need something that checks for Google Analytics cookies and then checks their privacy settings. If they accept then set them.

Comment: Check this site out -> http://www.civicuk.com/cookie-law/index

Comment: Why the down voting and closing? Looks clear and legit to me

Comment: Thanks the link :) That will work great. I had been finding it hard to find opt-in solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> http://www.civicuk.com/cookie-law/index

its a ready made solution